# prevent Gridview from repeating columns

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview that I am trying to populate from a dataset. I get all of the rows from the data to populate the gridview but when I try to build the columns it takes the columns once from the dataset and then once when I create the columns. I want to use the columns I create because I will want to couple of hyperlink columns.  Is there a way to clear the columns after I have attached the dataset as the gridview datasource? Or better yet, not use the columns from the dataset in the first place?

```
enter code here

 String connectionFromConfiguration = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Directors"].ConnectionString;
            DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionFromConfiguration))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spQryAllusers"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //Create a new DataSet.
               
                dsCustomers.Tables.Add("Customers");
 
                //Load DataReader into the DataTable.
                dsCustomers.Tables[0].Load(sdr);
                
            }
            con.Close();



                    HyperLinkField hlId = new HyperLinkField
                    {
                        DataTextField = "ID",
                        HeaderText = "Action"
                    };
                    gvUsers.Columns.Add(hlId);
                    BoundField email = new BoundField
                    {
                        HeaderText = "Email",
                        DataField = "EmailAddress"
                    };
                    gvUsers.Columns.Add(email);



                    
                    gvUsers.DataSource = dsCustomers;
                    gvUsers.DataBind();
                }
    }


        }
```

Comment: Absolute requirement to auto generate columns, or is using templated/defined columns in the GV a viable option?

Comment: It’s not a requirement. Can I create templates columns and still use the dataset as the data source?

Comment: Found the answer. autogeneratecolumns="false"

Comment: Yes, quite much why I was asking - if you template the columns then you don't auto-generated an more. And for setup, conditional formatting, you fin the row data bound event of use